# Excel Macro: Copying row values from one worksheet to a specific place in another worksheet, based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have only been working with macros in Excel for about 4 months now and have essentially been teaching myself by finding existing code and figuring out how it works. I am now a bit stuck.

I have a report in an Excel workbook. I need to copy the data across a number of worksheets (within the same workbook), based on the data that appears in column D. That is to say, I need to copy the entire row where Column D matches certain criteria. The original worksheet contains formulas, but I only want the values to appear when the data is copied.

I have been able to copy the data across, but I have two problems: 
1) the formulas are copying across, not just the values
2) the data appears in the new worksheet at cell A2, but I need it to start at cell A5

I am setting this up as a template, as the main report needs to be run and split every month, so the range from which I am copying will not be constant. This is a sample of the code I am currently using:

```
    Sub RefreshSheets()

    Sheets("ORIGIN").Select
    Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
    lr = Sheets("ORIGIN").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = Sheets("DESTINATION").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For r = lr To 2 Step -1
        If Range("D" & r).Value = "movedata" Then
            Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("DESTINATION").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
            lr2 = Sheets("DESTINATION").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End If


    Next r

    End Sub
```

I have tried adding ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues" after ".Range("A" & lr2 + 1)", but I get a compile error (Expected: end of statement). I am sure I have missed something obvious (this is what I get for using code I don't fully understand yet), but nothing I have tried so far has worked.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version uses a For loop (it can be slow with a lot of rows)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RefreshSheets()
    Dim wsO As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet, lrO As Long, lrD As Long, r As Long

    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORIGIN")
    Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DESTINATION")
    lrO = wsO.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lrD = wsD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If lrD < 5 Then lrD = 5

    For r = lrO To 2 Step -1
        If wsO.Range("D" & r).Value2 = "movedata" Then
            wsO.Rows(r).Copy
            wsD.Range("A" & lrD + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            lrD = lrD + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

This version uses an AutoFilter to copy all rows with "movedata" at once:

```
Public Sub RefreshSheetsFast()
    Dim wsO As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet, lrD As Long

    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORIGIN")
    Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DESTINATION")
    lrD = wsD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If lrD < 5 Then lrD = 5    'Makes sure the first row on DESTINATION sheet is >=5

    If Not wsO.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then wsO.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    With wsO.UsedRange
        .Columns(4).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="movedata"
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy        'Excludes the header (row 1)
    End With
    wsD.Range("A" & lrD + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wsO.UsedRange.AutoFilter    'Removes the "movedata" filter
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much this both works exactly as I need and makes more sense to me than my original code. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad it helped. As a note, your initial code copied the values starting at A2 because that was the first empty row found by `Sheets("DESTINATION").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` so what this code does is check the last row on Destination sheet and if it's smaller than 5, it increases it to 5: `If lrD < 5 Then lrD = 5`

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thanks for that, I can see where I went wrong now. You've just saved me a load of time.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the Copy and Paste as two separate requests:

```
Sub RefreshSheets()
  Sheets("ORIGIN").Select
  Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
  lr = Sheets("ORIGIN").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  lr2 = Sheets("DESTINATION").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For r = lr To 2 Step -1
      If Range("D" & r).Value = "movedata" Then
          Rows(r).Copy
          Sheets("DESTINATION").Range("A" & lr2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          lr2 = Sheets("DESTINATION").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      End If
  Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that solves the values issue. Any idea what I'm doing wrong when it comes to getting it to copy to A5 instead of A2?